# Inverse of a sparse 21x21 symbolic matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, sparse-arrays, inverse

I am trying to compute the inverse of the following symmetric sparse(density 0.37) 21x21 matrix involving symbolic expressions in the entries(the variables `a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6` shall correspond to positive half-integers). While there have been a number of similar questions floating around, I have, as yet, not managed to glean enough information to solve the problem. If one of the existing threads does indeed provide an answer which I am not recognising then feel free to call my attention to it, and sorry for the duplicate.

```
M = SparseArray[{
{1/2 (-2 a4 - 2 a5), 0, 0, a4/2, (I a4)/2, 0, a5/2, 0, (I a5)/2, a5/2, 0,
-((I a5)/2), a4/2, -((I a4)/2), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 1/2 (-2 a1 - 2 a4), 0, -((I a4)/2), a4/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (I a4)/2,
a4/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, a1/2, (I a1)/2}, 
{0, 0,1/2 (-2 a1 - 2 a5), 0, 0, 0, ((I a5)/2), 0, a5/2, (I a5)/2, 0, a5/2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -((I a1)/2), a1/2},
{a4/2, -((I a4)/2), 0,1/2 (-2 a2 - 2 a4), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
a4/2, (I a4)/2, 0, a2/2, 0, -((I a2)/2)}, 
{(I a4)/2, a4/2, 0, 0, 1/2 (-2 a4 - 2 a6), 0, 0, a6/2, (I a6)/2, 0, a6/2,
-((I a6)/2), 0, 0, 0, -((I a4)/2), a4/2, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/2 (-2 a2 - 2 a6), 0, -((I a6)/2), a6/2, 0, (I a6)/2, a6/2,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (I a2)/2, 0, a2/2}, 
{a5/2, 0, -((I a5)/2), 0, 0, 0, 1/2 (-2 a3 - 2 a5), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
a5/2, 0, (I a5)/2, a3/2, (I a3)/2, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 0, a6/2, -((I a6)/2), 0, 1/2 (-2 a3 - 2 a6), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, a6/2,
(I a6)/2, 0, 0, 0, -((I a3)/2), a3/2, 0},
{(I a5)/2, 0, a5/2, 0, (I a6)/2, a6/2, 0, 0, 1/2 (-2 a5 - 2 a6), 0, 0, 0,
0,-((I a6)/2), a6/2, -((I a5)/2), 0, a5/2, 0, 0, 0}, 
{a5/2, 0, (I a5)/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/2 (-2 a3 - 2 a5), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,   
a5/2, 0, -((I a5)/2), a3/ 2, -((I a3)/2), 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 0, a6/2, (I a6)/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/2 (-2 a3 - 2 a6), 0, 0, a6/2, 
((I a6)/2), 0, 0, 0, (I a3)/2, a3/2, 0},
{-((I a5)/2), 0, a5/2, 0, -((I a6)/2), a6/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
1/2 (-2 a5 - 2 a6), 0, (I a6)/2, a6/2, (I a5)/2, 0, a5/2, 0, 0, 0},
{a4/2, (I a4)/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/2 (-2 a2 - 2 a4), 0, 0,   
a4/2, -((I a4)/2), 0, a2/2, 0, (I a2)/2},
{-((I a4)/2), a4/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, a6/2, -((I a6)/2), 0, a6/2, 
(I a6)/2, 0, 1/2 (-2 a4 - 2 a6), 0, (I a4)/2, a4/2, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (I a6)/2, a6/2, 0, -((I a6)/2), a6/2, 0, 0,
1/2 (-2 a2 - 2 a6), 0, 0, 0, -((I a2)/2), 0, a2/2}, {0, 0, 0, a4/2,
-((I a4)/2), 0, a5/2, 0, -((I a5)/2), a5/2, 0, (I a5)/2, a4/2, (
I a4)/2, 0, 1/2 (-2 a4 - 2 a5), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, (I a4)/2, a4/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -((I a4)/2), a4/2, 0, 0, 
1/2 (-2 a1 - 2 a4), 0, 0, a1/2, -((I a1)/2)},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (I a5)/2, 0, a5/2, -((I a5)/2), 0, a5/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
1/2 (-2 a1 - 2 a5), 0, (I a1)/2, a1/2}, 
{0, 0, 0, a2/2, 0, (I a2)/2, a3/2, -((I a3)/2), 0, a3/2, (I a3)/2, 0, a2/2,
0, -((I a2)/2), 0, 0, 0, 1/2 (-2 a2 - 2 a3), 0, 0}, 
{0, a1/2, -((I a1)/2), 0, 0, 0, (I a3)/2, a3/2, 0, -((I a3)/2), a3/2, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, a1/2, (I*a1)/2, 0, 1/2 (-2 a1 - 2 a3), 0},
{0, (I a1)/2, a1/2, -((I a2)/2), 0, a2/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (I a2)/2, 0, 
a2/2, 0, -((I a1)/2), a1/2, 0, 0, 1/2 (-2 a1 - 2 a2)}
}]
```

Naively trying `Inverse[M]` results in exhausting memory pretty quickly. Since it has been possible to compute the determinant, my best shot has been trying to employ the Cayley-Hamilton method with the use of complete Bell polynomials [(here on wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Cayley.E2.80.93Hamilton_method). The inverse of M is given by the product of `1/Det[M]` with a whose essential components are powers of M and Bell polynomials of traces of powers of M. Implementing the formula in the link:

```
t[l_] := -(l - 1)! Tr[M^l] // Simplify
tlist = Table[t[i], {i, 1, 21-1}];
B[x_List] := Sum[BellY[Length[x], k, x], {k, 1, Length[x]}]; (*build    
complete Bell Polynomial from partial Bell Polynomials*)

S = IdentityMatrix[21] (-1)^(21 - 1)/(21 - 1)! B[Take[tlist, 21 - 1]] + 
Sum[M^(s - 1) (-1)^(21 - 1)/(21 - s)! B[Take[tlist, 21 - s]], {s, 2, 21-1}]
(*the first summand is just manually doing the s=1 part of the whole sum
where M^0=IdentityMatrix[21]*)
```

The inverse of M is then `Sum/Det[M]`.
`S` does indeed compute but it gives me such a large output that Mathematica won't display it without crashing let alone run `Simplify[]` on it(it saves to a 100kB .mx file).
Of course, this is is a result but I am guessing the final result should be somewhat more compact.

I'm not at all sure whether the Cayley-Hamilton method is the best way to go, but I'm happy for any improvements and indeed other suggestions as to how to compute the inverse of this matrix.

Comment: For what do you need the inverse of the matrix? What's the original problem you are solving?

Comment: A sparse matrix's inverse is often dense; unless you've good reasons to compute the inverse, **don't**.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke This is part of an effort to calculate the determinant of a Hessian matrix for the use of the saddle-point approximation of an integral. What I am calling M here is the Hessian to 0-th order in a collection of parameters(let's call them {t}) which the problem depends upon - we can rename `H_0:=M`. What I'm ultimately interested in is the determinant of the Hessian to second order in {t}. I have an expression `H_2`, i.e. the Hessian to second order in {t}. I am defining a matrix `h` through `H_2 = H_0 + h`. Using the identity `Det[M] = Exp[Ln[Tr[M]]]` one can arrive at:

Comment: `Det[H_2] = Det[H_0] (1+Tr[(H_0)^-1 h]+1/2((Tr[(H_0)^-1 h])^2-Tr[(H_0)^-1 h)^2])+O((H_0)^-1 h)^3))`
So this is why I need the inverse of H_0.
I'm just realising that the above expression will still contain some (up to) quartic expressions in the {t} - so I will have to throw those out at the end.
An alternative is just to calculate the full determinant of H_2 and then only keep the result up to second order - but computing that hasn't worked since H_2 is obviously much more complicated than H_0.
@J.M. I don't, in principle, mind dealing with a dense matrix as long as i can apply it to `h`

Comment: If you're multiplying the inverse with a vector or a matrix, as opposed to the needing the bare inverse, then you **don't** need the inverse. Use `LinearSolve[]`.

Comment: (1) I agree with @J.M. that `LinearSolve` is almost certainly the way to go. (2) There is a typo of a missing space, so that a "variable" is `Ia1`. (3) I'm trying this with `Method->"OneStepRowReduction"`. On the forward elimination it seems to get at least to row 18 (in a developer build with debugging information available). But it is bogging down. Not sure if it completes this part what will happen on the backward elimination.

Comment: Here is a result of sorts. `In[306]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 mInv = Inverse[mmat, Method -> "OneStepRowReduction"];]

Out[306]= {1929.418725, Null}

In[307]:= LeafCount[mInv]

Out[307]= 642060435

In[309]:= LeafCount[mInv[[1, 1]]]

Out[309]= 1300467

In[310]:= t11 = Together[mInv[[1, 1]]];

In[311]:= LeafCount[t11]

Out[311]= 133802` So it may be possible to get a factor of 10 or so compression by using `Together` on all entries. It will be slow though.

Comment: Further information. `Together` on the first row takes around 23 minutes on my desktop machine and produces a total leaf count of slightly under a meg. The original leaf count of that row is around 41.5 meg.

Comment: Thank you both for the further comments!
(1) @J.M. okay, I see what you meant by 'not needing the inverse'. So, I gave `LinearSolve[M,h]` a try last night(I presume this is what you meant, i.e. the desired matrix `(M^-1)h` solves the equation `M.X=h`). The kernel levelled out at occupying around 6,5 gigs before then running out after about 45mins. However, perhaps Daniel Lichtblau's suggestion of using `Together[]` beforehand might also help here.

Comment: Okay, I just deleted the previous comment since it contained some simple confusions. @DanielLichtblau Thank you, I corrected the typo. That looks pretty good! And only half an hour of computation time...I will try to obtain such a result using `OneStepRowReduction` as you do. And I presume you mean a leaf count of 1.000.000 when you say a meg? Also, regarding the previous comment - obviously you didn't mean using `Together[]` before computing, but I can also still try using `OneStepRowReduction` with `LinearSolve` also. Thanks, I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Leaf count for first row of inverse was 966224 after use of `Together`. But this is a post-processing step (as you realized). As for using `LinearSolve` I would suggest also doing so with  `Method -> "OneStepRowReduction"` (also as you had guessed).